# How do I change the APXS environment variable?

Tags: apache, unix, module, ftp

**How do I change the APXS environmental variable to use an apxs tool from a different location?**

---

I am trying to install an Apache module to my MAMP installation. I can successfully install the module using `$ apxs -cia mod_ftp_example.c`. However, the global `apxs` command is using the apxs tool that comes configured for the MAC OS X pre-installed Apache server, instead of using the apxs tool located in my MAMP build.

This means that when I execute the `apxs` command in Terminal, the module's .so file is installed here:

```
/usr/libexec/apache2
```

This is installing the module to the Apache server that comes with the Mac, and not **my** MAMP build. The path to the library modules that I want to install my module's .so file into is actually here:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/modules
```

Now, when I execute the command `$ whereis apxs`, I see the apxs tool is located in `/usr/sbin/apxs` - again, this is inside the httpd build for the default OS X Apache server and **not** my MAMP server.

My theory is that if I can change the `whereis` location of the apxs, then I can install my modules into the correct location. So how can I change that location? I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work :/

```
$ APXS=/applications/mamp/library/bin/apxs
```

Any ideas??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your just running APXS directly you can just use the full path
i.e. instead of

```
apxs -cia mod_ftp_example.c
```

you can do

```
/applications/mamp/library/bin/apxs -cia mod_ftp_example.c
```

If your running the apache ./configure.apxs you can do

```
export APXS=/applications/mamp/library/bin/apxs
```

If your doing some other kind of script you could always change the precedence of your path:

```
export PATH=/applications/mamp/library/bin/:$PATH
```